# How to capture arguments from Swift generic function

Tags: swift, generics, xctest

I have a Swift protocol that defines a generic function for making network requests. It looks something like this:

```
protocol TaskManagerProtocol {
    func run<V>(
        task: Task<V>,
        completion: @escaping (Result<V, Error>) -> Void
    )
}
```

This works great in production code, letting me make requests that receive different types of results. So far, so good.

**The problem:** For unit testing, I want a Test Spy that captures the arguments, especially the closure. The spy looks like this:

```
class TaskManagerSpy<Value>: TaskManagerProtocol {
    var callCount = 0
    var task: [Task<Value>] = []
    var completion: [(Result<Value, Error>) -> Void] = []

    func run<V>(
        task: Task<V>,
        completion: @escaping (Result<V, Error>) -> Void
    ) {
        guard V.self == Value.self else {
            fatalError("run<V> doesn't match init<Value>")
        }
        callCount += 1
        self.task.append(task)
        self.completion.append(completion)
    }
}
```

My intention is to have test code instantiate `TaskManagerSpy<SomeType>` and inject that into the System Under Test, which calls `run<V>(task:completion:)`. But as it stands, the `append()` calls fail to compile:

```
Cannot convert value of type 'Task<V>' to expected argument type 'Task<Value>'
```

and the same for the closure. If I comment out these lines, the test succeeds without triggering the fatal error.

**Question:** I have demonstrated that the types are the same. Is there a way to coerce one type into the other, so that I can capture the arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, as you said, you've already asserted `V.self == Value.self`, you ought to be able to force cast `task`:

`self.task.append(task as! Task<Value>)`

Same thing for `completion`:

`self.completion.append(completion as! ((Result<Value, Error>) -> Void))`

Comment: At first glance the type-casts look "weird", but this is for testing only, and the fact that TaskManagerSpy just happens to conform to the protocol, but has to do completely different things than the actual implementation of a TaskManager, I believe this is a viable approach. But, still I have the feeling, there's a better approach  :)

Comment: Agreed that force casts "feel" wrong, and it usually means bypassing a SwiftLint rule, but I can say with some confidence this is likely the "best" approach. Generic functions are probably the most annoying contract to mock in Swift's type system.

Comment: Just a little comment, you may want to use XCTUnwrap with message instead of force cast to make tests more clean and readable :)

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by using an `associatedtype` in TaskManagerProtocol instead of having a generic type `V` on `func run`:

```swift
protocol TaskManagerProtocol {
    associatedtype ValueType
    func run(
        task: Task<ValueType>,
        completion: @escaping (Result<ValueType, Error>) -> Void
    )
}

class TaskManagerSpy<Value>: TaskManagerProtocol {
    var callCount = 0
    var task: [Task<Value>] = []
    var completion: [(Result<Value, Error>) -> Void] = []

    func run(
        task: Task<Value>,
        completion: @escaping (Result<Value, Error>) -> Void
    ) {
        callCount += 1
        self.task.append(task)
        self.completion.append(completion)
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this approach more, however - and this is a big however - this rises the question how the existing code must be refactored. There's probably a single instance of a TaskManager handling all the different value types `V`. Probably this actually is a Decodable and/or Encodable - depending whether this is the "Input" or "Output" of that task. Now, after making the protocol a "PAT", there need to be more than one instance of a TaskManager (type dependent on `V`), which may affect the client code in a heavy way. The type `V` is also exposed to the client, it's not an implementation detail.

Comment: This approach will mean that you can no longer have any properties of type `TaskManagerProtocol` without making the entire enclosing type generic. The usage outside of tests is likely not what you want.